# Is there a Vim color scheme that matches Sublime's default Monokai?

Tags: vim

I'd like it to have decent syntax highlighting too - especially for JavaScript. (e.g. method names should be highlighted).

Here's Sublime:

[image]

I've come across a few. Here's [sickill/vim-monokai](https://github.com/sickill/vim-monokai):

[image]

and [tomasr/molokai](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai/):

[image]

But, as you can see from the screns, they don't seem to match Sublime's colors/syntax highlighting. Are there any others?

Comment: I don't use this colorscheme, but have you tested in gvim or terminal vim? and don't put too much effort on color stuff.

Comment: I'm using terminal vim, haven't used gvim. Color is not as important as highlighting. I really like being able to see the key names highlighted in a JS object.

Comment: give gvim a try. for terminal you can set different color palette. and you won't in terminal vim have exactly same color as Sublime's. since terminal has only 256 colors.

Comment: Hm, good to know. One of my main motivations for trying out vim is to stay in the terminal, next to my servers, etc, so I'm not sure gvim would interest me. Are any terminals capable of more than 256 colors?

Comment: @SamSelikoff You can start looking at https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728, which tries to document terminal support for true color.

Comment: AFAIK this style wasn't invented by ST, but it's the monokai color theme by Wimer Hazenberg

Comment: This deleted answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25186612/20654  (use molokai from: https://github.com/tomasr/molokai )

Answer (score 6):

First, GVim/MacVim will be mandatory if you want your colors to match Sublime's as terminal emulators are usually limited to 256 colors.

Second, if you only want Vim's colors to match Sublime's, you'll probably need to tweak the colorscheme itself or send their author a formal feature request.

Third, Vim doesn't highlight method names by default so no colorscheme will give that to you for free but you can try the example given under `:help tag-highlight`. There's also [this plugin](https://bitbucket.org/abudden/taghighlight) and [this one](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags).

All the "tag highlighting" solutions depend on the presence of a `tags` file.

Comment: Interesting, looks like if I do some work I may be able to swing it. Thanks for the references!